# Excel UNICARDENAS: buscar datos y obtener valores de rango...con excepciones!

Tags: excel

No sé qué es lo correcto, pero se me ocurre que editar mi anterior pregunta, era lo indicado... antes que hacer una nueva!

Tengo que hacer algo similar con UNIRCADENAS, pero obteniendo como resultado, los valores de un rango "D:K", omitiendo los 2 últimos valores conseguidos.

Pensé que iba a ser súper fácil, editando simplemente la fórmula que me ofreció @Pollo anteriormente (para Excel 2019)... pero no consigo hacerlo!! Sinceramente, no termino de entender la lógica con la que funciona la fórmula y me está volviendo loco!

Alguna idea?? Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Tengo este rango de datos:

[image: origen]

y necesito convertirlo en esto:

[image: destino]

O sea, según el "color" ingresado en A, obtener en B (separados por comas), los valores en el rango B:G de cada fila, para cada una de las referencias... Siempre omitiendo el segundo, penúltimo y último valor (coloreado aquí en el ejemplo sólo para resaltar la referencia).

Alguien podrá darme una mano con esto... Que a mi, ya me venció?
Muchas gracias!  =)

Answer (score 2):

> Uso `;` como separador. Cambiá a `,` si es tu caso

#### Para Excel 365

Viendo que los datos de la primera fila están en `$B2:$G2`

```
=UNIRCADENAS(", ";VERDADERO;INDICE(FILTRAR($B2:$G2;$B2:$G2<>"");FILTRAR(SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2));SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2))<>2)))
```

---

**Explicado** (de adentro para afuera):

1. Obtenemos la cantidad de celdas a mostrar (contar no vacías, restarle 2, que de mínimo sea 1 para mostrar)

   ```
   MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2)
   ```
2. Convertir en matriz de 1 a ese número. Por ejemplo si son 4 elementos a mostrar, será `{1;2;3;4}`

   ```
   SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2))
   ```
3. Sacar el `2` de esa matriz.

   Si la fórmula del punto (2) fuese `res`, sería

   ```
   FILTRAR(res,res<>2)
   ```

   Para la fórmula completa es:

   ```
   FILTRAR(SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2));SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2))<>2)
   ```

Listo con la parte de la derecha... a la izquierda

4. Obtener la matriz de todas las celdas no vacías

   ```
   FILTRAR($B2:$G2;$B2:$G2<>"")
   ```
5. Con `INDICE` usamos los del punto (3) para filtrar en el punto (4)

   Si fuese siempre obtener las celdas 1, 3 y 4, sería

   ```
   INDICE($B2:$G2;{1;3;4})
   ```

   Para la fórmula completa

   ```
   INDICE(FILTRAR($B2:$G2;$B2:$G2<>"");FILTRAR(SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2));SECUENCIA(MAX(1;CONTARA($B2:$G2)-2))<>2))
   ```

Con esto, ya tenemos la matriz de todas los valores que nos interesa.. Para unir todo con comas usamos `UNIRCADENAS`, que es la fórmula que está al principio.

---

#### Para Excel 2019

La misma lógica que en el punto anterior, con fórmulas que funcionan en Excel 2019 (se ve más feo y más ofuscado, pero funciona). Consiste en ir sacando de la matriz con todas las celdas (`$B2:$G2`) primero la 2da posición y luego quedarse con las que están en posiciones antes de la cantidad de celdas no vacías - 2.

```
=UNIRCADENAS(", ";VERDADERO;SI(COLUMNA($B2:$G2)<>COLUMNA($B2)+1;SI(COLUMNA($B2:$G2)<CONTARA($B2:$G2)+COLUMNA($B2)-2;$B2:$G2;"");""))
```

---

**Explicado** (por orden de evaluación):

1. Nos quedamos con todas las celdas que no sean la 2da:

   ```
   SI(COLUMNA($B2:$G2)<>COLUMNA($B2)+1; ..... ; "" )
   ```

   para filtrar, va viendo en qué columna está. Entonces toma las columnas del rango (`{2;3;4;5;6;7}`) y compara que sean diferente a la `COLUMNA($B2)+1`. Es decir que no sean la columna `3` (la columna C).

   El resultado va a ser siempre `{VERDADERO;FALSO;VERDADERO;VERDADERO;VERDADERO;VERDADERO}`... Va a evaluar el resto de la fórmula para todo menos para la columna C, que es falso y devuelve `""`.
2. El resto va al `SI()` anidado. Acá vemos que no sean los últimos 2 valores

   ```
   SI(COLUMNA($B2:$G2)<CONTARA($B2:$G2)+COLUMNA($B2)-2; ...... ;"")
   ```

   Con `CONTARA($B2:$G2)` obtenemos la cantidad de valores que no están vacíos, y si le sumamos la columna de inicio y le restamos 2, nos da el número de columna a partir de la cual no mostrar.

   Por ejemplo, si están los 6 valores, sería

   ```
   CONTARA($B2:$G2)+COLUMNA($B2)-2
          6        +    2       -2
                     6
   ```

   que es la columna F, que no se incluye.

   Si tuviésemos 5 valores en `$B2:$G2`, toda la condición se evaluaría así:

   ```
   SI(COLUMNA($B2:$G2)<CONTARA($B2:$G2)+COLUMNA($B2)-2  ; ... ; "")
   SI({2;3;4;5;6;7} <       5          +    2       -2  ; ... ; "")
   SI({2;3;4;5;6;7} < 5                                 ; ... ; "")
   SI({VERDADERO;VERDADERO;VERDADERO;FALSO;FALSO;FALSO} ; ... ; "")
   ```
3. Así, todos menos la columna C (punto 1), y sólo si está antes de los últimos 2 valores (punto 2), nos da `VERDADERO`, evaluando

   ```
   $B2:$G2
   ```

   que es el valor de la celda en sí.

   Por ejemplo, si tenemos los valores 101,202,333,444,5, nos da como resultado

   ```
   {101;"";333;"";"";""}
   ```
4. Por último, `UNIRCADENAS()` descarta los valores vacíos y junta todo con comas.

Comment: sos un crack!! Perdón por no responder antes, pero me surgieron unos inconvenientes y tuve que despegarme del tema por un rato!
Mil gracias por tu ayuda!!

Te comento...

Comment: Veo que el tema es demasiado complicado... y aún con una explicación tan APB como la tuya, me cuesta entenderlo! (ni a palos que hubiera podido de alguna manera, llegar a resolverlo por mis medios), por lo que empecé por intentar "probar" con lo que me pasaste... y me encontré DE UNA con algo que no entiendo y es que mi Excel parece no reconocer "FILTRAR" como un nombre de función válida (devuelve un error de nombre!)... por lo que arranqué mal con el tema... y apenas quise empezar, quedé varado! jejeje

Estoy utilizando Excel 2019 para sistemas de 64bit... alguna idea?

Comment: Encontré la respuesta a mi propia pregunta, en https://www.desafiandoexcel.com/funciones-de-excel/funcion-filtrar-en-excel/

"La función FILTRAR es una de las nuevas funciones implementadas a partir de Excel 365 en el año 2020. Es una función de búsqueda y referencia que nos permite filtrar un rango de datos de forma simple en función de los criterios que necesitemos."

Estoy al hornooo!! jejeje

Comment: UNA parte resuelta: el segundo valor de cada rango, lo omito no importando esa columna del origen de datos!! Por lo que lo que me queda por resolver, es más simple:
De acuerdo al "Color" ingresado en la 2 tabla (o rango), el tema quedaría entonces, reducido a importar los valores del rango B:G... pero sí, omitiendo los dos últimos de cada fila.

Para el caso, tampoco pude terminar de resolverlo... por lo que agradeceré cualquier ayuda!  =(

Comment: Sos crack... 2 veces!! Funciona perfecto como array! EXACTO lo que necesitaba!
Ahora intentaré estudiarlo para entender qué es lo que está haciendo y cómo funciona! jejeje
MIL GRACIAS!  =))

Comment: @Speedbit editado para Excel 2019